# How do I determine final ValueChange event on Kendo Angular DatePicker

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

I need to set min and max dates for a Kendo Angular DatePicker.  This is pretty straight forward using `[(max)]="maxDate" and [(min)]="minDate"` and this works when using a mouse and clicking the DatePicker.

The problem is when using keyboard entry a user can select dates outside the min and max dates.  I have a valueChange event but it fires with every keystroke.  I cannot determine when the user is finished entering the entire date and then simply setting the date to min or max as needed.  I could set an onFocus event for the next control but that would be kludgy.

This is a snippet of the html code:

```
  <kendo-datepicker 
    id="dpFirstPaymentDate" 
    (valueChange)="onFirstPaymentDateChange($event)" 
    [(value)]="firstPaymentDate" 
    [(max)]="maxDate" 
    [(min)]="minDate" 
    [(focusedDate)]="firstPaymentDate" 
    [rangeValidation] = "true" 
    title="First Payment Date">
  </kendo-datepicker>
```

The angular code is this:

```
 protected onFirstPaymentDateChange(/*event: EventEmitter*/ value: Date): void {

        if (value > this.maxDate) {
          // This does not appear to be working
          value = new Date(this.maxDate);
          this.firstPaymentDate = new Date(this.maxDate);
        }
        else if (value < this.minDate) {
          value = new Date(this.minDate);
          this.firstPaymentDate = new Date(this.minDate);
        }

        this.maturityDate = new Date(value);
        this.maturityDate.setMonth(value.getMonth() + this.term);


    }
```

A complete plunker example is here: [Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/1IZO9BGKDinHPAW58Ogr)

Comment: what about on blur? but onFirstPaymentDateChange then need to get value from this.firstPaymentDate, i changed your [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bq7xUfP9OVTwWWgHnpwi?p=preview) a bit and i think it is a better way to know when the user is done changing the date

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly.  Please add this as an answer and I will accept it,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay since my comment is actually on point, so actually instead of using onchange event we should use the on blur event

```
<kendo-datepicker 
    id="dpFirstPaymentDate" 
    (blur)="onFirstPaymentDateChange($event)" 
    [(value)]="firstPaymentDate" 
    [(max)]="maxDate" 
    [(min)]="minDate" 
    [(focusedDate)]="firstPaymentDate" 
    [rangeValidation] = "true" 
    title="First Payment Date">
</kendo-datepicker>
```

and just a bit change on the onFirstPaymentDateChange function, since we are not getting the date value, might just get it with `this.firstPaymentDate` and we can continue to set the logic (max value). Here's working example in [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bq7xUfP9OVTwWWgHnpwi?p=preview)